# Lodash filter not working with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I'm using lodash library to filter an array of objects but for some reason the filter it's returning the same value I pass to it, any idea what am I doing wrong?

This is the function I use to transform data:

```
getFlattenFields(schema)
    {
        let flatten = _.flatten(schema.fields);
        console.log('flatten',flatten);
        let filtered = _.filter(flatten, item => item.element != 'loader' || item.element != 'button' );
        console.log('filtered',filtered);
        return filtered;
    },
```

And my schema variable is this object:

```
formSchema: 
    {
        fields: 
        [
            [ 
                { id: 'email', label: '', default: '', element:'input', type: 'text' },
                { element: 'button', text:'Enviar', icon:'fas fa-reply' }, 
            ],
            [
                { element: 'loader' }, 
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Do you wanted to return element which are not  button and loader?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your condition:

```
item => item.element != 'loader' || item.element != 'button'
```

That condition will always evaluate to true, because every possible `element` will be unequal to either `loader` or `button`.  My guess is you want: `!(item.element === 'loader' || item.element === 'button')`.

Comment: `!(item.element === 'loader' || item.element === 'button')` using DeMorgan's law this transforms to `item.element !== 'loader' && item.element !== 'button'` which is (IMO) easier to read.